# Виртуальная вебкамера

Tags: поиск-программ, streaming, web-camera, трансляция

Мне нужно транслировать содержимое рабочего стола как видео с веб-камеры на компьютере с Windows 10. Существуют ли программы, желательно с открытым исходным кодом, которые позволяют это сделать?

Comment: Скайп -> Демонстрация экрана?

Comment: @Anamnian это нужно для потокового анализа содержимого экрана в node-opencv, скайп для примера

Comment: OBS Studio годится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу [решили](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qt-dxgi-screenshot) обходным путем, захватывая буффер экрана напрямую из [dxgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Graphics_Infrastructure)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]